# About "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock" ERROR

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-desktop, docker-daemon

I'm trying to install and run docker desktop for Mac with Apple silicon,
I've installed docker with ~~brew install `cask docker`, and tried to run docker build, only I got "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?" message.

I've tried most of the solutions that came up from Googling including stackoverflow for past 2 days, but I still couldn't solve the problem. Most solutions suggest to restart Docker, but every time I actually try to "start" the docker, the message "Docker Desktop in Stopped" appears and nothing changes.

My question is, if I want to restart docker like most solutions do, is there any other way than clicking on the application icon in the docker desktop?(`systemctl` doesn't work in my environment) Or could there be other causes (such as  something went wrong about the path of docker.sock) that I don't know about?

I've tried restarting(only it never works..) and `ls -l $HOME/.docker/run/docker.sock`(it doesn't works, either), also re-installing...